# Why the operator "*" between a dataframe and a series is giving me a len(firstSeries)*len(secondSeries) with NaNs?

Tags: python, pandas, datetimeindex

I got `res = dataframe * dataframe['column']` with `<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>` for the first dataframe and `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>` for `dataframe['column']`

And it outputs me :  `res : 2020-08-17 05:00:00  2020-08-17 05:15:00  2020-08-17 05:30:00 ...               dtime                                                                                                    2020-08-24 16:45:00                     NaN                  NaN                  NaN ...             2020-08-24 16:30:00                     NaN                  NaN                  NaN ...              2020-08-24 16:15:00                     NaN                  NaN                  NaN ...              2020-08-24 16:00:00                     NaN                  NaN                  NaN ...              2020-08-24 15:45:00                     NaN                  NaN                  NaN ...               ...                                                                                               2020-08-17 06:00:00                     NaN                  NaN                  NaN ...               2020-08-17 05:45:00                     NaN                  NaN                  NaN ...              2020-08-17 05:30:00                     NaN                  NaN                  NaN ...              2020-08-17 05:15:00                     NaN                  NaN                  NaN ...             2020-08-17 05:00:00                     NaN                  NaN                  NaN ...`

Everything that I find tells me that "*" is suppose to give me : `res :                                          dtime                                                                                                    2020-08-24 16:45:00                     floatValue                                                  2020-08-24 16:30:00                     floatValue                                                   2020-08-24 16:15:00                     floatValue                                                   2020-08-24 16:00:00                     floatValue                                                   2020-08-24 15:45:00                     floatValue                                                      ...                                                                                               2020-08-17 06:00:00                     floatValue                                                    2020-08-17 05:45:00                     floatValue                                                   2020-08-17 05:30:00                     floatValue                                                   2020-08-17 05:15:00                     floatValue                                                  2020-08-17 05:00:00                     floatValue`

I'm sure I'm missing something, but I can't find what.

Edit :

```
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame({"angles": [0, 3, 4], "degrees": [360, 180, 360]}, index=["circle", "triangle", "rectangle"])
other = pandas.DataFrame({"angles": [0, 3, 4]}, index=["circle", "triangle", "rectangle"])
print("df * other :", df * other)
```

is giving me :

```
df * other :
           angles  degrees
circle          0      NaN
triangle        9      NaN
rectangle      16      NaN
```

as expected. So maybe it has to do with the datetimeIndex.

Edit :

```
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame({'angles': [0, 3, 4], 'degrees': [360, 180, 360]}, index=['2020-08-17 05:30:00', '2020-08-17 05:15:00', '2020-08-17 05:00:00'])
other = pandas.DataFrame({'angles': [0, 3, 4]}, index=['2020-08-17 05:30:00', '2020-08-17 05:15:00', '2020-08-17 05:00:00'])
df.index = pandas.to_datetime(df.index, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
other.index = pandas.to_datetime(other.index, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

print("df * other :", df * other)
```

is giving :

```
df * other :         angles  degrees
2020-08-17 05:30:00       0      NaN
2020-08-17 05:15:00       9      NaN
2020-08-17 05:00:00      16      NaN
```

So it's not the datetimeIndex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your small example, you are multiplying df * df[i.e. other ]. you will get the same problem if you use df *df.angles [i.e. df * series ]

but in the main problem, you are using df * series. try using df * pd.DataFrame(df.col) .

in df * series:  it compares column wise same as  df.multiply(df.series,axis=1)
you can try  df.multiply(df.series,axis=0) as well